# toObjectId for arrrays of String to be used with lookup and aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have 2 models, one is Group and another is Students. Group looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8d28ef7e0e542854b7b904"),
    "name" : "Homeroom ",
    "year" : 2019,
    "schoolID" : ObjectId("5c1a735fc98da061141475a1"),
    "teachers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5c1a7677c98da061141475aa",
            "firstName" : "Ayam"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5c1a7677c98da061141475a9",
            "firstName" : "Itik"
        }
    ],
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-03-16T16:48:47.372Z"),
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2019-03-16T16:48:47.372Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "status" : 1,
    "students" : [ 
        "5c1a79f7c98da061141475b7", 
        "5c3bfea37774fb0b55000cb5", 
        "5c1a7c69c98da061141475bb", 
        "5c3bfea37774fb0b55000cb4", 
        "5c1a7d32c98da061141475be", 
        "5c3bfea37774fb0b55000cb7"
    ]
}
```

Where the field `students` above stores the _id (in String format) of students inside Students model.

Now I'm trying to do a lookup with aggregate, and I comes up with something like this:

```
Group.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(groupID) } },
            { $lookup: { 
              from: "Students", localField: "students", foreignField: "_id", as: "studentList"  
            } },
              { $unwind: "$studentList" },
              { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$students" } }
          ], function(err, result){
            if (err){
              console.log("imin err 102: " )
              console.log(err)
            }else{
              console.log("imini 105 result")
              console.log(result);
            }
          });
```

Now I understand that the code above won't yield any result, since `students` inside Model Group is stored as String, while the _id inside model Student is an ObjectId. Mongodb now have `$toObjectId` but since my Model holds an array of String, I don't know how to implement `$toObjectId` correctly.

Here's sample documents for Students

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1a79f7c98da061141475b7"),
    "firstName" : "Ibrahim",
    "kelasID" : ObjectId("5c429f9906f2a805bc6cd494"),
    "lastName" : "Ali",
    "schoolID" : ObjectId("5c1a735fc98da061141475a1"),
    "year" : 2018,
    "__v" : 0,
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2018-12-25T04:27:47.909Z"),
    "checkIn" : false,
    "checkInStatus" : 1,
    "contactNo1" : "012225656",
    "father" : "Ali",
    "fatherID" : "8852245",
    "idType" : 0,
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2018-12-25T04:27:47.909Z"),
    "mother" : "",
    "motherID" : ""
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3bfea37774fb0b55000cb5"),
    "idType" : 0,
    "checkIn" : false,
    "checkInStatus" : 1,
    "year" : 2019,
    "schoolID" : ObjectId("5c1a735fc98da061141475a1"),
    "kelasID" : ObjectId("5c1a7534c98da061141475a3"),
    "firstName" : "Umar",
    "lastName" : "Bin Al-Khattab",
    "contactNo1" : "601222",
    "status" : 1,
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-01-14T03:14:43.597Z"),
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2019-01-14T03:14:43.597Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c1a7c69c98da061141475bb"),
    "idType" : 0,
    "checkIn" : false,
    "checkInStatus" : 1,
    "year" : 2018,
    "schoolID" : ObjectId("5c1a735fc98da061141475a1"),
    "kelasID" : ObjectId("5c1a7540c98da061141475a5"),
    "firstName" : "Abdul Rahman",
    "lastName" : "Affan",
    "father" : "Affan",
    "fatherID" : "54321",
    "contactNo1" : "602288",
    "status" : 1,
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2018-12-25T04:30:16.130Z"),
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2018-12-25T04:30:16.130Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: `$toObjectId` is only supported in mongodb V4.0 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map) over the `students` field to convert the `String` ids to `ObjectId`

```
Group.aggregate(
  [
    { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(groupID) } },
    { "$addFields": {
      "students": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$students",
          "in": { "$toObjectId": "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }},
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "Students",
        "localField": "students",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "studentList"
      }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$studentList" },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$students" } }
  ],
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("imin err 102: ");
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("imini 105 result");
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Somehow the solution above will return an empty `result` for me. If I just try to remove the lines `{ "$unwind": "$studentList" },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$students" } }` , I will get a result, but empty `studentList`

Comment: `Students` must be `students` in from expression of `$lookup`

Comment: I added an update on my question above.. it seems `$map` part is working as intended, but not the `$lookup` part

Comment: Did you change `Students` to `students`?

Comment: yes I did.. now my lookup looks like this `"$lookup": {
        "from": "students",
        "localField": "students",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "studentList"
      }`

Comment: Could you post the sample documents from the students collection too.

Comment: I've added some sample document from Students collections, thanks

Comment: See here https://mongoplayground.net/p/2XkvPZz_lFz what it returns

Comment: Somehow I copy pasted your code from mongoplayground.net and it works. Thanks a lot for your help Anthony Winzlet. I really really appreciate it. The only thing that needs to change is `"newRoot": "$studentList" ` instead of `"newRoot": "$students" `

Comment: @imin Saved me! The **from in $lookup** document name must be the same as the one in the DB, not the name of the schema. My scheme name is *Knowledge* (noncountable), however it's named *knowledges* in the DB